# Calling a PowerShell cmdlet in DotNet Core (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, service

I've developed a PowerShell module. At a very basic level, the module watches a folder and creates a blob in an Azure Storage Account' container. I'd like to run it as a Windows Service written in C#. I know there are simpler ways, but I am using it as a learning exercise.

The PowerShell part of the project works.

The service starts and then immediately stops with the error:

`The term 'Invoke-FileSystemWatcher' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

(Invoke-FileSystemWatcher is a cmdlet in the module).

The `File.Exists()` if statement returns true.

There are a few references to this error around the Internet, including some here on SO. I have tried all their suggestions but I can't get it to "see" the cmdlet.

Below is my class file (warts and all):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace arc.ocr.windows.service
{
    public class PSArcOcrUploader : BackgroundService
    {

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            WriteEventLog _log = new WriteEventLog();

            // Test path to PS module
            string moduleFile = @"C:\path\to\myModule.psd1";
            if( File.Exists(moduleFile))
            {
                _log.Write($"Module file found: {moduleFile}", 18399, logTypeEnum.Information);
            } 
            else
            {
                _log.Write($"Module file not found: {moduleFile}", 18398, logTypeEnum.Error);
            }

            // Call the InitialSessionState.CreateDefault method to create
            // an empty InitialSessionState object, and then add the
            // elements that will be available when the runspace is opened.
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] {moduleFile});

            SessionStateVariableEntry var1 = new SessionStateVariableEntry("PathToMonitor", "C:\\Temp\\Inbox", "Target folder for MFD scans.");
            iss.Variables.Add(var1);

            // Call the RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState)
            // method to create the runspace where the pipeline is run.
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
            runspace.Open();

            // Call the PowerShell.Create() method to create the PowerShell object,
            // and then specify the runspace and commands to the pipeline.
            // and create the command pipeline.
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.Commands.AddCommand("Invoke-FileSystemWatcher");
            //ps.AddCommand("Invoke-FileSystemWatcher");
            //ps.AddArgument("PathToMonitor");
            //ps.AddParameter
            ps.Invoke();
            // Call the PowerShell.Invoke() method to run the pipeline synchronously.
            // foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
            // {
            //     Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1}",
            //         result.Members["Name"].Value,
            //         result.Members["Value"].Value);
            // } // End foreach.

            // Close the runspace to free resources.
            if (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
            {
                runspace.Close();
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

There may be other issues, however, this is my current blocker.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers, I'd be very grateful if you could share.

T.I.A

Comment: Whar is `Invoke-FileSystemWatcher` command? Do you define it in `myModule.psd1`?

Comment: @picolino, I've updated the question. `Invoke-FileSystemWatcher` is a cmdlet in `MyModule`.

Comment: Please show it's cmdlet definition for us. Error text definitely says that powershell can't recognize it as cmdlet.